# How to parse a multi row/line array in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to parse my array with multi row and multi line, I try with foreach or for loop, but I didn't succeed

```
var student = [
      {name:"alan",title:"al",platform:"test1",orderNumber:1 },
      {name:"frank",title:"fr", platform:"test2",orderNumber:1},
      {name:"bryan",title:"br", platform:"test3",orderNumber:1}
      ];

for (var i = 0; i < student.length; ++i) {
        window.alert(student[i]);
      }
```

It don't work. how could I parse this array with a loop and display it please? thanks a lot

Comment: What is `student`? Did you mean `array.length`? And what do you mean by "parsing it" and "display it"?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No, the alert is just to verify my data. But I would like ti use each data ... student.name , student.title .... etc

Comment: Are you trying to display a table from your data?

Comment: @user12240399, You can access it using student[i]['name'] or student[i]['title'] inside the loop... You can test it in alert or console.log(student[i]['title'])

Comment: thanks a lot. "Nikhil" give me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate on properties of an object.

```js
var student = [
  {name:"alan",title:"al",platform:"test1",orderNumber:1 },
  {name:"frank",title:"fr", platform:"test2",orderNumber:1},
  {name:"bryan",title:"br", platform:"test3",orderNumber:1}
];

student.forEach(item => {
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
  });
});
```

Comment: sorry to disturb you, but I would like to have an array student2 from student. I would like to have in student2 two row : student2 = [
  {data1:"alan",data2:"al" },
  {data1:"frank",data2:"fr"},
  {data1:"bryan",data2:"br"}
];     ... it's possible? thanks

Comment: @user12240399 - Yes, it is possible. Take a look at [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and give it a try. If you don't get it, let me know or ask a new question on this site.

Comment: Yes I see it , but I don't understand how to have a specific row ... key.name ? key[name]?

Comment: @user12240399 - Take a look at this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-quxib8). You can see the output in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a live link https://dotnetfiddle.net/aQJP3W

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index18</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#theButton").click(function () {
                var student = [
                    { name: "alan", title: "al", platform: "test1", orderNumber: 1 },
                    { name: "frank", title: "fr", platform: "test2", orderNumber: 1 },
                    { name: "bryan", title: "br", platform: "test3", orderNumber: 1 }
                ];

                $.each(student, function (index, value) {
                    alert(value.name + "-" + value.title + "-" + value.platform + "-" + value.orderNumber);
                });
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Go" id="theButton" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```